# Set notation for greatest $n$ in ordered subset

Tags: notation, set-theory

I am trying to describe the following situation:

$ X = \{x_i \dots x_n\} $ This is the set of all job applicants.

$Y$ is a subset of $X$ where $M = 1$. Each $x_i$ has an associated $m_i$ that can be $\{0,1\}$ representing whether or not an applicant is "hireable".

Each applicant also has an "applicant strength rating" ($\alpha_i$). $Z$ would be the set I would get if I took $Y$, ordered it in decreasing $\alpha_i$ order, and chose the top $\beta$ individuals, with $\beta > 0$.

I would like to succinctly describe set $Z$. So far, I have:

$$
\forall ~ X \in \mathbb{N}^n, ~ X=\{x_1 \dots x_n\} \\
Y \subset {X | M = 1}  \\
Z ={\rm argmax}_{Y, ~ |Y|=\beta}~\sum_{y \in Y} y
$$

Comment: I don't understand your notation. How is M = 1 related to the problem ? What does it mean to take the sum of elements of Y, when Y is the set of applicants?

Comment: I'm guessing M = 1, restricts X to only applicants with $m_i$ = 1. And summing elements of Y refers to summing the associated strength scores? and argmax is taking the largest such summation for |Y| of size β ?

Comment: If what I described is what you mean, then what you have works.

Comment: $X$ is the pool of all applicants.
I want all applicants in $X$ where $m_i=1$ (this is an arbitary variable assigned to each applicant, it doesn't really matter what it means, but I just want all applicants where $m_i=1$). Then take this subset and order them in descending order by another variable ($\alpha_i$) which is a score given to each applicant. Then take the top $\beta$ number of individuals from that subset, where $\beta$ is any number greater than 0 (i.e, "take the top five scoring applicants").

Comment: My attempt at an answer was taken from this SEMath question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463502/mathematical-expression-for-n-largest-values-in-a-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I reformulate the task a bit and make it a bit more concrete.

- Given is a set $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ of pairwise different elements, which is the set of job applicants.
- We consider a map $m$:
  \begin{align*}
  &m:X\to \{0,1\}\\
  &m(x_i)=m_i\qquad\qquad \qquad  1\leq i\leq n
  \end{align*}
  which determines if a job applicant is hireable (i.e. $m_i=1$).
- We want to consider certain sets $Y\subseteq X$ of *hireable* job applicants, i.e. we consider
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{Y\subseteq m^{-1}(1)=\{x\in X|m(x)=1\}\subseteq X}
  \end{align*}
  In order to appropriately select $Y$ we introduce a rating function $\alpha$:
  \begin{align*}
  &\alpha:X\to\mathbb{R_0^{+}}\\
  &\alpha(x_i)=\alpha_i\qquad\qquad \qquad  1\leq i\leq n
  \end{align*}

> Finally we want to select the top $\beta\in\mathbb{N}$ hireable job applicants, which have the best rating $Z$. We are therefore looking for
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{Z=\underset{{Y\subseteq m^{-1}(1)}\atop{|Y|=\beta}}{\arg\max}\,\,\sum_{y\in Y}\alpha(y)}
> \end{align*}

*Notes:*

- Depending on the functions $m$ and $\alpha$ there may be more than one solution which results in $Z$.
- On the other hand, if there is only a small number $|m^{-1}(1)|$ of hireable job applicants, the condition on $\beta$ might be too strong, so that there is no solution at all.

*Hint:* The meaning of $M$ and its relationship with $X$ is not clear and is ignored in this answer. OPs notation $X\in\mathbb{N}^n$ is not admissible, since $X$ is not an *ordered* $n$-tuple of natural numbers.

Comment: @DylanRussel: Many thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Given your set up, we let:

$ X = \{x_i \dots x_n\} $

M = { $m_i \dots m_n$}

Let g: X $\rightarrow$ M

such that g($x_i$) = $m_i$

We'll call this the applicant Hireability function

$M_0$ = {$x_i$ | $g(x_i)$ = 0 }

Let Y $\subset$ X \ $M_0$  and |Y| > 0

Let A = { $a_i \dots a_n$}

Let h: Y $\rightarrow$ A

such that h($x_i$) = $a_i$

We'll call this the Applicant Strength Function

We define a sequence:

$b_0$ = smallest $a_i$ such that
h($x_i$) = $a_i$

$b_{n+1}$ = smallest $a_i$ > $b_n$ such that h($x_i)$ = $a_i$

if $a_i$ = $a_j$ we order by the index, so if i < j then $a_i$ < $a_j$

So we have α nondecreasing sequence of terms:

Note: if you want a nonincreasing sequence instead, just let $b_0$ be the largest, instead of the smallest etc...

<$b_n$ | n < m> for some m$\in$ω

Let 0 < β and  δ = m - β ≥ 0

Let z = { $x_i$ | h($x_i$) ≥ $b_δ$ }

Let's look at an example:

Let X = { $x_0$,$x_1$,$x_2$ }

For simplicity let's assume Y = X

Suppose

h($x_0$) = 1 = h($x_1$)

h($x_2$) = 2

So

$b_0$ = h($x_0)$ = 1

$b_1$ = h($x_1$) = 1

$b_2$ = h($x_2$) = 2

Suppose we wanted the applicant with the best strength score.

Let β = 1, δ = 3 - β = 2

Recall: z = { $x_i$ | h($x_i$) ≥ $b_δ$ }

So, z = { $x_i$ | h($x_i$) ≥ $b_2$ }

z = {$x_2$} As desired.